# $Tr(\alpha_{i}^{n})=\alpha_{1}^{n}+...+\alpha_{d}^{n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I want to show $Tr(\alpha_{i}^{n})=\alpha_{1}^{n}+...+\alpha_{d}^{n}$ where $\alpha_{i}$ is algebraic integer of degree d and the $\alpha_{j}$ are it's conjugates.

Is there any quick way to show it without going into automorphisms?

Is this true:
$Tr(\alpha^{n}_{i})=\sigma_{1}(\alpha^{n}_{i})+...+ \sigma_{d}(\alpha^{n}_{i})=\sigma_{1}(\alpha_{i})^{n}+...+ \sigma_{d}(\alpha_{i})^{n}$?

thanks

Comment: do you need more information?

Comment: Yes what you've written is correct. As for showing it without mentioning automorphisms, that would be pretty hard considering you would need to reference the idea of conjugate algebraics.